# Detect interactive process at kernel level

Tags: debugging, linux-kernel

I'm trying to detect interactive processes at the kernel level. 
For example, if a user clicks on some application window I want to detect all processes spawned form that user interaction.
Also my question doesn't finish there. There are cases that those processes started by a user interaction will communicate with some other existing process, say a background service, and wait for that service response back before giving some GUI feedback. I want to be able to keep track of that whole workflow and say something like process A started by a mouse click at time1 then communicated with process B at time2 then process B responded back to process A at time3 and finally process A finishes at time4. Something like a granular step by step of what's happening under the hood for workflows triggered by interactive actions. And finally say interactive workflow X had a response time of Y and involved a set M  of processes.

Any ideas?
What I've been trying so far is to instrument (place a trace) system calls related to Inter Process Communication but no luck. Maybe I'm not tracing at the correct spots.

Thanks!

Comment: what IPC do you mean? looks like you are using a graphic user interface.

Comment: actually I don't care about a specific user interface. It could be anything triggered by any peripheral (mouse, keyboard, remote control, etc). I placed traces in system calls related to signals, pipes and sockets: kill, pread, pwrite, read, readv, recv, recvfrom, rcvmsg, send, sendmsg, sendto, write, writev.

Answer (score 0):

if a user click on an application spawns child processes then most probably the newly spawned processes will be the children of that. From kernel you can check the child processes list. On the instance of click processing from the parent process, that is going to be the `current` task in the kernel. So, you can iterate over the `client->children` list and find the processes. Its possible that the current processes already have children, then you need to keep track of the existing children list and track the new addition.

Comment: thanks for the answer. but my question was incomplete. I just edited it.

Comment: But that was not my problem, does it?